# How to conditionally change the table th tag text content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-table, conditional-statements, contains

I am new to JavaScript & jQuery. I want to conditionally change the `th` text based on the content of an array.

```
var categoryNames = "Category : 1~!_Basis~#Category : 2~!_QUALITÄT~#Category : 3~!_GRUNDDATEN~#Category : 4~!_DISPOSITION~#Category : 5~!_VERTRIEB~#Category : 6~!_EINKAUF~#Category : 7~!_BUCHHALTUNG~#Category : 8~!_Optionen";

var replacetext = ["_Basis","_QUALITÄT","_GRUNDDATEN","_DISPOSITION","_VERTRIEB","_EINKAUF","_BUCHHALTUNG","_Optionen" ];

var res = categoryNames.split("~#");

for (var i=0; i< res.length; i++){ 
  var pattern = res[i];
  var rep  =  replacetext[i]; 
  $(function(){
    alert(pattern);
    var m=  $('table tr th:contains("'+pattern+'")');  
    m.text(rep);
  });  
}
```

Above code is just replacing for the last pattern which is "**Category : 8~!_Optionen**" by "**_Optionen**". Please suggest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't include document.ready inside for loop.

```js
var categoryNames = "Category : 1~!_Basis~#Category : 2~!_QUALITÄT~#Category : 3~!_GRUNDDATEN~#Category : 4~!_DISPOSITION~#Category : 5~!_VERTRIEB~#Category : 6~!_EINKAUF~#Category : 7~!_BUCHHALTUNG~#Category : 8~!_Optionen";
var replacetext = ["_Basis", "_QUALITÄT", "_GRUNDDATEN", "_DISPOSITION", "_VERTRIEB", "_EINKAUF", "_BUCHHALTUNG", "_Optionen"];
var res = categoryNames.split("~#");

for (var i = 0; i < res.length; i++) {
  var pattern = res[i];
  var rep = replacetext[i];
  alert(pattern);
  //var m = $('table tr th:contains("' + pattern + '")');
  //m.text(rep);
  alert(rep)
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Accept answer if  its helps :) . Happy Coding.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to do by wrapping the code block that is replacing the pattern in a jQuery object.  The for loop can simply do the replacement.

```
for (var i=0; i< res.length; i++)
{ 
    var pattern = res[i];
    var rep  =  replacetext[i]; 

    alert(pattern);
    var m = $('table tr th:contains("'+pattern+'")');

    m.text(rep);
}
```